# Can we parse a terraform "variables.tf" file in Java? If so how to implement the same

Tags: java, terraform

Please find the Sample snippet of Variable.tf file, I want to fetch only the subscription_id, plan_id, user_id. I don't want to fetch location, since it already have default value set.

```
variable "subscription_id" {
description = "My subscription id"
}

variable "plan_id" {
description = "My tenant id"
}

variable "user_id" {
description = "My user id"
}

variable "location" {
type="string"
default="Sydney"
description="The name of the location in which your account is 
created. "
}
```

---

Comment: @AUsername I approved your edit, but it may be better to let the OP learn how to post code as code himself rather than just doing it for him in the future.

Comment: So you need show us what you have did first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Regex to find the various variables, then parse the found variables using another Regex. One way to do this would be the following

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>> parse(String input){
    HashMap<String, Map<String, String>> variables = new HashMap<>();
    Matcher variableMatcher = Pattern.compile("variable \"(\\S+?)\"\\s*\\{\\s*((?:.|\\n)+?)\\s*}").matcher(input);
    Pattern bodyElementPattern = Pattern.compile("(\\S+)\\s*=\\s*\"(.+)\"");
    while (variableMatcher.find()){
        HashMap<String, String> bodyElements = new HashMap<>();
        Matcher bodyElementMatcher = bodyElementPattern.matcher(variableMatcher.group(2));
        while (bodyElementMatcher.find()){
            bodyElements.put(bodyElementMatcher.group(1),bodyElementMatcher.group(2));
        }
        variables.put(variableMatcher.group(1),bodyElements);
    }
    return variables;
}
```

Here you are going to get a map of variable name to variable contents, where the variable Contents are represented as another map of the components' names and values.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wants to use just one line and get only the default value if its available. Here is what I did.

```
pattern_string = "(?:variable.*\\\"(\\w+)\\\"(?:.*\\s)*?(?:\\s*default\\s*=\\s*(\\S*)|}))";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pattern_string);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tfFile);

while (matcher.find()) {
   String variable_name = matcher.group(1);
   String default_value = matcher.group(2);
   if (default_value == null) {
     // do stuff
   }
}
```

You can find a break down of the regex here https://regex101.com/r/Ec3ykt